# Xamarin Clear many items in grid

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a grid but it have So many childrens ( Like 800-900 ) And when i press refresh button it must refresh all childrens like delete olds and create new ones. When i use `grid.Children.Clear()`

its take so long time for clear all and create new ones. How can i fix it ? when i google it they say create new grid instead of use children.clear but how can i dispose first one ? How can i refresh my datas faster when i click button ? I need help about it . Thanks for helpings!

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  There is no way we can suggest a "faster" way to do something when you have not shown us how you are doing it in the first place.  But I would suggest that if you have a grid with "800-900" children your UI is very poorly designed.

Comment: @Jason I taking my datas from some json. Thats why i have that much children. Cant i dispose and create new one ? How can i dispose ? I really searched and cant found any information.

Comment: Can you see 900 children at once? If not - and it would seem unlikely - then you need a container that dynamically loads the data into view.

Comment: This is so bad practise .... You can use CollectionView or ListView

Answer (score 0):

Why do you produce children? You can use CollectionView for good performance.. also the features you want are easier for CollectionView.

I recommend it for CollectionView and its refresh structure.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JY900hOQCKQ